# What’s the probability of picking a minimum of 3 red balls

Tags: probability, combinations

So i got this math question and I can’t seem to figure out the answer.

There are $7$ vases with each $9$ different colored balls in them. You pick $1$ ball from each vase without looking. What is the probability that you pick a minimum of $3$ red balls.

Personally I think it is 1 - P(2 red balls) + P(1 red ball) + P(0 red balls).

So that will be $1-(\frac{1}{9}^0*\frac{8}{9}^7+\frac{1}{9}^1*\frac{8}{9}^6+\frac{1}{9}^2*\frac{8}{9}^5)\approx0,5$

Or am I forgetting something?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: there is only one red ball in every vase.

Comment: You have to take into account of which vases give the red ball.

For example for $1$ red ball, there are $9$ different cases corresponding to from which of the $9$ vases you get a red ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need inclusion-exclusion here. It is equivalent to a binomial distribution  with $p= 1/9, n = 7$ and we need to find $P(X>=3)$

which is more easily obtained as $ 1 - P(X \leq2)$

$= 1 - [\binom 90 (\frac19)^0(\frac89)^9+\binom 91 (\frac19)^1(\frac89)^8 +\binom 92 (\frac19)^2(\frac89)^7] $

Comment: Oh, you didn't intend inclusion-exclusion, just forgot to put parentheses properly.

Comment: Merry Xmas !$\;\;$ :)